# How to run .cmd files and commands

Tags: powershell, build

I go to folder `C:\projects` and run script `init.cmd` that initializes environment, the I go to any project, e.g. `C:\projects\my_app` and run command `build` that builds the project. I need to automate it in PowerShell. How to that? My try:

```
Set-Location "C:\projects"
Invoke-Item init.cmd   # c:\projects\init.cmd

# Wait for init.cmd finish its work

$paths = Get-Content $paths_array
foreach ($path in $paths)
{
   Set-Location $path
   Invoke-Item build   # build is set in paths
   # Wait for build finish its work
}
```

Comment: Where does `$paths_array` come from? What kind of command is `build`? An executable? What doesn't work about your approach? Do you get an error?

Comment: @AnsgarWiecher  `$path_array` is array of directories of projects, come as an input, it already exists before the program starts. `build` is `build.cmd` script, that internally calls `.exe` . I don't how to wait for init.cmd and build.cmd, and how to run the script in the context of cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
Set-Location "C:\projects"
$cmdpath = 'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c'
Invoke-Expression "$cmdpath init.cmd"

$paths = Get-Content $paths_array
foreach ($path in $paths)
{
   Set-Location $path
   Invoke-Expression "$cmdpath build"
}
```

Also if you are not interested in your scripts output and you just want them to be executed you can use `Out-Null` like this:

```
Set-Location "C:\projects"
$cmdpath = 'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c'
Invoke-Expression "$cmdpath init.cmd" | Out-Null

$paths = Get-Content $paths_array
foreach ($path in $paths)
{
   Set-Location $path
   Invoke-Expression "$cmdpath build" | Out-Null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Batch scripts can be run directly from PowerShell and should be executed synchronously, i.e. the call should only return after execution completed.

There are various ways to call a batch script, but personally I prefer using the call operator (`&`):

```
Set-Location "C:\projects"
& .\init.cmd

Get-Content $paths_array | ForEach-Object {
  Push-Location $_
  & .\build.cmd
  Pop-Location
}
```

Note that you *must* specify the (absolute or relative) path to the batch script, since PowerShell doesn't include the current directory in the search path.